# Remove Double Menu in Mobile View and Have one Menu Only

Tags: menus, troubleshooting

There is a double menu that shows up on Mobile on the following website [www.plotterpro.com/newsite](https://plotterpro.com/newsite)[image] I have been attempting to hide and it just does not want to go away.

Answer (score 0):

The menu can be be removed by following methods

1. CSS - display:none;
2. Check in menu section of wordpress and check if
       you ticked multiple menu's
3. Modifiy functions.php and remove the the
       menu